# Extract file name with the folder containing the file

Tags: python

If I have the following file path:

```
'G:\\My Drive\\A\\B\\C\\EH\\2021_12_17.txt'
```

How can I get the file name with the folder containing the file:

```
'EH\\2021_12_17.txt'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) here:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r'G:\My Drive\A\B\C\EH\2021_12_17.txt')
result = path.relative_to(path.parents[1])
```

P.S. Use `str()` if you need string result.

Comment: Does it matter that his string has `\\` instead?

Comment: @BruceWayne, what do you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry! I forgot to escape it -- OP's string is `G:\\My Drive\\A\\B\\C\\EH\\2021_12_17.txt`

Comment: @BruceWayne, double slashes have been used in code to escape slash, I've used `r` prefix instead. Try to `print()` both strings.

Answer (score 2):

Try `join` with `str.split`

```py
path = 'G:\\My Drive\\A\\B\\C\\EH\\2021_12_17.txt'
'\\'.join(path.split('\\')[-2:])  # -> 'EH\\2021_12_17.txt'
```

Comment: `.rsplit('\\', 2)` should be slightly better